# Deletion of User and home directory from NFS

Tags: nfs, user-management, opensuse, nis

I have 10 systems with  opensuse installed in each of them.I have created 2 servers such that one is NIS and other is NFS , i have added lets say 5 users to NIS and their corresponding home directories were rsynced to second system (NFS). NOw i want to write a script that can delete the user and also delete corresponding NFS located home folder.

I tried userdel but it was unable to delete directory from NFS

Mt /etc/exports of NFS server is

```
homescis *(fsid=0,crossmnt,rw,root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: The issue here is probably not `usermod`, but the permissions with which the file system is exported - specifically, how the server treats requests that originate from root-owned client processes).  If this is so, no script is going to be able to do what you want.  Could you cut-and-paste into the question the relevant line in `/etc/exports` on the NFS server?

Comment: homescis *(fsid=0,crossmnt,rw,root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)

Answer (score 0):

On the server, change `root_squash` to `no_root_squash` and do an `exportfs -av`. That is causing requests issued by root on the client to be interpreted without privilege on the server; if you want tools like usermod to run, root privilege is needed on the `/home` filesystem.